# Can I bypass yes-or-no question while resetting tracker

Tags: command-line, tracker

I want to make a desktop shortcut to reset the tracker using `tracker-reset -e`. It shows a yes or no question every time. Can I bypass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, in general, "echo" an answer to the command, as in

```
echo y | tracker reset -e
```

which indeed will automatically provide the answer "y" to the prompt.

If a terminal application requests more prompts, you could supply multiple answers as in

```
printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n' y 1 q | terminalprogram
```

In this hypothetical example, the first prompt of program `terminalprogram` is answered with `y`, then with a `1`, then with `q`. The same effect could be achieved by including each answer on a new line in a text file `answers.txt` and then feeding the contents of the file to the program, as in

```
cat answers.txt | terminalprogram
```

or as in

```
terminalprogram < answers.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

### `yes`

From [coreutils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/coreutils) package. [`man`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) page:

> **yes** - output a string repeatedly until killed
>
> yes [STRING]...
>
> Repeatedly output a line with all specified STRING(s), or 'y'.

So in your case would be:

```
yes | tracker reset -e
```

Comment: Is it not working with a simple echo command?

Comment: Is just different, another way of resolving the problem, maybe more elegant, general and powerful. That's why we can have several answers for one question :)